# The Elevator Problem

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-state, programming

Today I(z) walked into an elevator and did not press the key to the floor to which I wanted to go.

As there were 2 other people x and y who had pressed the keys 2 and 3 respectively.

I wanted to go to the 2nd floor but nither x or y knew about it, so using a quantum computer or circuit how can x or y deduce whether I want to go to there floor or the probabilities of me going to 2nd or the 3rd floor.

Can we transform the question to ask what is the probability of z exiting on every floor, Please suggest?

Comment: x or y can use quantum teleportation algorithm to get the state of your mind; unfortunately the state of your mind will be destroyed during the process and you don't know anymore which floor you wanted to go,

Comment: Unless x and/or y have prior information about your behaviour, movements, or plans, there's nothing that they can do (in theory or practise) without *actually talking to you*, and that's not something I would model by a quantum algorithm. --- is this actually the question you wish to solve, or is it meant to stand for some other problem?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I am new to quantum computing in general so trying to figure out how and what can a quantum computer be applied, this question came to me after hearing all the marketing and buzzwords around quantum computing.

Comment: Based on the information provided, the probability is trivial to calculate $$p(\text{exit next floor})=\frac{1}{ \text{total # floors} \, - \, \text{current floor}}.$$  With vast amounts of additional information, you could build an AI/ML type model that ultimately reaches enough complexity that quantum processors could become relevant, but the question is not well posed to say anything meaningful about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any "person" (x or y) can obtain the state of z using the quantum circuit consisting of CNOT and Hadamard gates and $Z$ gate; the circuit is actually a simplified version of quantum teleportation; let x be in the state $|0\rangle$, that is he wants to go to the floor 2 (state $|1\rangle$ means floor 3). Applying CNOT to z (control qubit) and x entangles z and x, and then you need to apply Hadamard gate to z and measure it.

If you measure $|1\rangle$, x already contains the initial state of z; if you measure $|0\rangle$, you need to apply $Z$ gate to x.

Either way in the end x contains the initial state of z while the state of z is destroyed by measurement.

For more details see [Prof. Vazirani's lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5NylvbqY44).

Comment: I don't see why one would introduce quantum computing for this problem. Any 'person' can also obtain z just by a reversible CNOT gate. This is particularly relevant if both x and y wish to learn z, and it's more appropriate if they don't intend to lobotomize z in the process. Involving quantum is just a distraction and adds nothing of interest.

Comment: Plain CNOT works if only z determined which floor to go; if not, the above algorithm is need. BTW this is good question, because it makes one think.

Comment: In the original question: 'I wanted to go to 2nd floor, but nither x or y knew about it'. But also, there are better ways to get at this idea than to dress it up as a question about mind-reading (actually, mind-swiping) fellow passengers in elevators.

Comment: In the end the original question asks about probabilities, that is why I assumed that z is uncertain which floor to go.

Comment: @kludg The problem as stated has no quantum behavior whatsoever.  The probabilities are entirely classical.  Trying to frame this as a problem suited for quantum computation is only going to add confusion to an already difficult subject.

Comment: @ChainedSymmetry Schrodinger cat problem (the cat dead and alive) has no quantum behavior whatsoever too, still it is the most popular illustration of quantum superposition. I wonder why you don't see the *real* quantum question behind the elevator setup.

Comment: @kludg Schrödinger's cat most definitely involves quantum behavior - the heart of the paradox is the interaction of a radioactive substance with a Geiger counter.

Comment: @ChainedSymmetry when it comes to the cat, it is 100% classical.

Comment: @kludg No, it's not.  The whole point of the paradox is that the Copenhagen Interpretation implies that superposition within a quantum system (radioactive decay $+$ Geiger counter) could create superposition of a macroscopic system (cat), which is/was purportedly absurd.